# Socket в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 8888)) ################
sock.send('hello')

data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print (data)
```

Интерпретатор говорит `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` на строчку, выделенной ####

И еще вопрос: почему в той же строчке в примере используются двойные скобки?

UPD: подключаясь по `telnet localhost 8888` - запущенный сервер реагирует

Comment: Я имею вредную привычку не верить на слово, так что можно скриншот с одновременно работающим телнетом и питоном с ошибкой?

Answer (score 3):

По поводу двойных скобок всё достаточно очевидно: метод принимает один аргумент - кортёж, из двух элементов.

Comment: в скобки объединяются несколько переменных, и из этого всего получается кортеж, который является аргументом уже внешних скобок. верно?

Comment: @neko69 картёж (tuple) создаётся с помощью запятых в Питоне. Дополнительные скобки нужны, чтобы отличить случай вызова с одним или с двумя аргументами. Если убрать дополнительные скобки, то вызов с двумя аргументами происходит в этом случае.

Comment: @neko69, да всё верно. Вот так f(a,b) будет функция с двумя аргументами, а так f((a,b)) - функция с одним аргументом, который является двухчленным кортежем.